# NSUserDefault is being cleared automatically after random period of time

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I am using these methods to save and get data from NSUserDefaults. But NSUserDefaults is being cleared automatically in device after random period of time. I checked the project-

- I am not saving any nil or empty string using saveUserName method.
- Not using removeObjectForKey, removePersistentDomainForName to reset NSUserDefault.

**Code...**

```
+(NSString *) getUserName{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kAccUserNameKey];
}

+(void)saveUserName:(NSString *) value {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:kAccUserNameKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

After saving data using saveUserName, I get data properly using getUserName, even after restarting app. But It has been reported that data is being lost sometimes.(getUserName is called from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and applicationWillEnterForeground) Why NSUserDefault is resetting? any idea??

From documentation

> - (NSUserDefaults *)standardUserDefaults 
>     Description
>     Returns the shared defaults object. **If the shared defaults object does not exist yet**, it is created with a search list containing the names of the following domains, in this order:
>
>   - NSArgumentDomain
>   - A domain identified by the application’s bundle identifier
>   - NSGlobalDomain
>   - NSRegistrationDomain

Is that means, sometimes shared object does not exist yet and its returning nil? whats the solution?

Comment: Have you checked that whether `saveUserName:` is called anywhere else in the code with nil parameter?

Comment: Yes I have checked, I am getting data from textfield of a alertview. Save button of alert view is disabled if name is not valid. So there is no chance to save nil or empty sting. And it is interesting that not only username, all keys are cleared. For example appFirstRun tag, appIsRated tag etc...

Comment: - (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    
    NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    if( [inputText length] >= 1 )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

Comment: are all keys are stored in the same manner. like username through alertView?

Comment: yes,  name, pass, phone key store user info using alert view; appFirstRun, appIsRated does not depend on alertview...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49480/discussion-between-himanshu-joshi-and-devojyoti-aich)

Comment: All the values stored in NSUserDefaults are lost through installations, i.e. if you have saved a value, uninstall the app and install it again, any previously saved values won't be available anymore.

Comment: @singingAtom I am not uninstalling app. Problem is- Sometimes I am not getting data from userdefaults after app launch or app wakes from background.

Comment: Have you been able to fix the issue? I am having the same problem for a while now and can't find the source of the problem.

Comment: @Daniel Did not find any specific reason or any solution, then I converted it to Core Database.

Answer (score -1):

Did you create NSRegistrationDomain domain for your data dictionary via [-registerDefaults:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults%3a) ?

As [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-97292) says:

> At launch time, an app should register default values for any
>   preferences that it expects to be present and valid.

You can do it like this, to make `NSUSerDefaults` work properly:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary * defaultsDictionary = @{kAccUserNameKey : @"default name"}
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsDictionary];       

    return YES;
}
```

In the `defaultsDictionary` you should specify all data keys you will use in app with their default values.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but no luck. I saved user info to a plist(also sync userdefault) after user filling a form. Then I update registerdefaults with default value[from plist] when app launches or come to forground. But some clients have reported that it did not solved the issue.

Comment: It didn't solve the resetting problem. It only offers the default values, but not the previously saved ones.